# Rails - collection_select prompt value + Disable it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, materialize

When I use `form.select` I have found out to preprend the selections with a 'fake' option. I.E.

```
<%= f.select(:status, [["Choose a Status", 0], ["Active"], ["Cancelled"], ["Prospect"]], {:disabled => 0, :selected => 0}, {}) %>
```

And to use `disabled` and `selected`. This worked perfectly. However, if I wanted to use a controller's response, or a query instead of a manually typed array - I am unsure how to prepend it.

EX

```
<%= form.collection_select(:client_id, current_user.clients.order(:name),:id,:name, :class => "browser-default")%>
```

I have tried using `prompt` which did give me the fake option I was interested in - And I liked that it took the `edit` functionality into consideration when rendering, but it was always selectable.

I am using `MaterializeCSS` which seems to be modifying the Input a bit, and it is no longer just an `option` and `select` tags.

TL;DR - When using `collection_select` how can I leverage `prompt`, and make it unable to be selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, this is using bootstrap select2.

application.js

```
$(".dropdown").select2({
  theme: "bootstrap"
});
```

view file

```
<%= f.select :skills, Profession.find_by_id(1).try(:categories).collect{|c| [c.title, c.id]}, {}, {multiple: true, class: "dropdown form-control", required: true} %>
```

This is working this way.
[image]